# need a regex to get different output

Tags: python, regex

```
import urllib.request
import re

##check for phone numbers

web_page = 'https://www.secdaemons.org/admin'
with urllib.request.urlopen(web_page) as response:
   page_bytes= response.read()
the_page = page_bytes.decode('utf-8')
phone_number = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}')
phone_no = re.findall(phone_number, the_page)
print(phone_no)
```

This is the above code, and I'm getting the output as:

```
['495.186.5818', '377)590.0376', '312-555-4747']
```

i need a clean output which are separated by "-" as:

```
['xxx-xxx-xxxx', 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', 'xxx-xxx-xxxx']
```

Comment: Are you asking that you _only_ want to match `xxx-xxx-xxxx` numbers, or do you want to edit all your current matches to match this format?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , i want to edit all the current matches to match the format .

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your current output, we can try the following list comprehension:

```py
inp = ['495.186.5818', '377)590.0376', '312-555-4747']
output = [re.sub(r'\D', '-', x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['495-186-5818', '377-590-0376', '312-555-4747']
```

Note that this approach is robust to *any* separator between the digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a simple replace after, for example:

```
import urllib.request
import re

##check for phone numbers

web_page = 'https://www.secdaemons.org/admin'
with urllib.request.urlopen(web_page) as response:
   page_bytes= response.read()
the_page = page_bytes.decode('utf-8')
phone_number = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}')
phone_no = re.findall(phone_number, the_page)
cleaned_numbers = [number.replace('.', '-').replace(')','-') for number in phone_no]

print(cleaned_numbers)
>>> ['495-186-5818', '377-590-0376', '312-555-4747']
```